# PhoneAuthProvider in Kotlin getting implementaion error

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

When I try to register user via phone authentication, I'm getting runtime error

> kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented

and my code is

```
val phoneAuth: PhoneAuthProvider = PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance()
    phoneAuth!!.verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+91xxxxxxxxxx",        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this@MainActivity,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallBacks)

 val mCallBacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(p0: String?, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken?) {
            super.onCodeSent(p0, p1)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[`TODO`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html) basically throws [`NotImplementedError`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-not-implemented-error/index.html). You may just replace `TODO` with a comment like `// TODO`.

Answer (score 1):

Well just remove TODO( ... ) from your implemented Functions and you are good to go ! For instance

```
override fun onNegativeButtonPresssed() {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

Remove from TODO.